# Task not running

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've created a stream and task procedure that takes any newly inserted JSON data in a raw table and inserts them into a flattened table. The stream doesn't seem to work.

This is the query I've used

```sql
-- Create Stream raw_flat_stream
create or replace stream raw_flt_stream on table raw append_only = true;

-- Create Task raw_flat_stream_task
create or replace task raw_flt_stream_task
    warehouse=small_whs
    schedule='5 MINUTE'
when system$stream_has_data('raw_flt_stream')
as
insert into raw_flt
select
    json_data['col1'] col1,
    json_data['col2'] col2,
    ...
    python_udf(json_data['array1']) coln
from
    raw_flt_stream;

-- Resume Task raw_stream_task
alter task raw_flt_stream_task resume;
```

Things to consider:

- This is using a Python UDF in the script
- This is not the only stream setup on the raw table
- If I run the `insert` statement manually it works (inserts the data and clears the stream)
- If I run manually `execute task raw_flat_stream_task` or wait until it kicks off it does not work. Even when checking `information_schema.task_history()` this task does not appear to be running. However when I run `show locks in account` I can see

| session | resource | type | transaction | transaction_started_on | status | acquired_on | query_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | RAW_FLT | PARTITIONS | 123 | 2022-05-31T08:20:09.664Z | HOLDING | 2022-05-31T08:20:09.728Z | abc |
| 123 | RAW_FLT_STREAM | STREAM | 123 | 2022-05-31T08:20:09.664Z | HOLDING | 2022-05-31T08:20:09.728Z | abc |

So it seems running the task just locks it in place. There's no error to indicate a timeout or something wrong with the script (since manually running the insert works).

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was using this query to check if the task is running

```sql
select * from table(information_schema.task_history()) where schema_name = 'my_schema'
```

And didn't return any result with `NAME = 'RAW_FLT_STREAM_TASK'`. But when running

```sql
select * from table(information_schema.task_history(
  scheduled_time_range_start=>dateadd('day',-1,current_timestamp()),
  result_limit=>1,
  task_name=>'raw_flt_stream_task'
))
```

It returned

| query_id | name | database_name | schema_name | query_text | condition_text | state | error_code | error_message | scheduled_time | query_start_time | next_scheduled_time | completed_time | root_task_id | graph_version | run_id | return_value | scheduled_from |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | RAW_FLT_STREAM_TASK | MY_DB | MY_SCHEMA | INSERT... | system$stream_has_data('raw_flt_stream') | CANCELLED | 000630 | Statement reached its statement or warehouse timeout of 3,600 second(s) and was canceled. | 2022-05-31T08:20:04.308Z | 2022-05-31 08:20:08.669 +0000 | 2022-05-31 08:25:04.308 +0000 | 2022-05-31 09:20:09.835 +0000 | abc | 1 | 123 | null | EXECUTE TASK |

To fix it I've changed the warehouse size and it worked

```sql
create or replace task raw_flt_stream_task
    warehouse=2xl_whs
    schedule='5 MINUTE'
when system$stream_has_data('raw_flt_stream')
as
insert into raw_flt
select
    json_data['col1'] col1,
    json_data['col2'] col2,
    ...
    python_udf(json_data['array1']) coln
from
    raw_flt_stream;
```